# How to receive Json with spaced fields-names in asp.net web-api?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In my MVC-4 Web-API server, I receive a Json string that contains spaces in it's names:

```
{ "field name" : "some value" , "simpleName" : "some string" }
```

I defined a `Model` class, e.g:

```
public class SomeJsonModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field name")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string SimpleName { get; set; }
}
```

Now `SimpleName` passes through (in spite it's first letter capitalization mismatch, which is good), but `FieldName` becomes `null`.

How can I successfully receive Json that has spaces in it's fields' names (predefined - I cannot change the client data source) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [DataContract] on your class:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeJsonModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "field name")]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SimpleName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is more info about this:

- on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx):  "*Apply the DataMemberAttribute attribute in conjunction with the DataContractAttribute to identify members of a type that are part of a data contract.*"
- a [Json.NET issue](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22431) relating to the DataMember's Name property being ignored.  The resolution for that was to "*Put DataContract on the class.*"

Comment: The `DataContract` doesn't work, I guess cause it's not `WCF`. But the Json.NET seems to be the answer.